# Finding similarity between a word and a sentence (like "restart" and "turn off and on")

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, word2vec

I am using Word2Vec for text vectorization. It is doing a good job but some cases it is failing. For example "turn the computer off and on" and the sentence "restart the computer" does not have a very good similarity score, even though they mean the same thing. Doc2Vec is not doing a good job as my inputs are usually a couple of sentences and not a document.

Can anyone please suggest an approach which would give a good similarity score between "turn on and off" and "restart" and also other combinations like that?

Comment: Use pre-trained embeddings, and form the document embeddings through [averaging the tf-idf scores](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SyK00v5xx) or concatenation of summary statistics (min, max, mean, std)

Comment: This question related to this other question https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22536/detect-related-sentences/22948#22948

Answer (score 0):

If you are training your word2vec by yourself than you should increase your training dataset. You can easily get the Wikipedia [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#English-language_Wikipedia). If you are using a pretrained model, you can always fine tune it with additional data.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to build sentence vectors using vectors generated for Words.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760935/how-to-get-vector-for-a-sentence-from-the-word2vec-of-tokens-in-sentence) covers the different techniques you could use to achieve it.